# Ruby multi-line evaluation block within array.reject! - a better way?

Tags: ruby

I have a section of code that rejects array-of-hash entries based on a missing match in another array-of-hash.  I would like to perform multiple actions inside the `reject!()`.  The code below works as intended but is this the optimal way to return `true` to `reject`?

I've tried replacing the `miss =` with an `if con.any? ... end` wrapper but the `if` statement doesn't return `true`.

Do I really need to spell out the `true if miss` line listed below?

```
libs.reject! do |x|   
  miss = con.any? {|h| [:lib, :f2, :f3].all?{|z| x[z]==h[z]}}
  print_err("ERROR, libs #{x[:lib]} not found with #{x[:f2]} and #{x[:f2]}") if miss
  (mm_xls.add_row ["MISS", x[:lib], x[:f2], x[:f3]], :style => r_entry) if miss
  true if miss
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tap` to execute a block yielding the receiver, then return that same object:

```
libs.reject! do |x|
  con.any? {|h| ... }.tap do |condition|
    print_err(...) if condition
    # etc ...
  end
end
```

In this case, `tap` returns the result of the `any?` block.

Comment: Love the `.tap` method! Great answer

Comment: Thanks Zach, that's much cleaner!

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid creating miss variable this way

```
libs.reject! do |x|   
  if con.any? {|h| [:lib, :f2, :f3].all?{|z| x[z]==h[z]}}
    print_err("ERROR, libs #{x[:lib]} not found with #{x[:f2]} and #{x[:f2]}")
    mm_xls.add_row ["MISS", x[:lib], x[:f2], x[:f3]], :style => r_entry
    true
  end
end
```